# Flash - Actionscript if ... else statement

Tags: flash, actionscript, if-statement

I have a basic actionscript code which basically shows a list depending on the value of a text box.

```
if (txtValue.text = "0")
{
    lstFilm.visible = false;
}
else if (txtValue.text = "1")
{
    lstFilm.visible = true;
}
```

The problem i'm having with it is instead of it changing the visibility of the list, it changes the value in the box. Any ideas why or how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `==` which is the equality operator not `=`the assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! How simple!

Answer (score 1):

An if statement typically needs to evaluate a 'true' or 'false' operation.

By using:

```
if(txtValue.text = "0") { ... }
```

You are actually assigning the value "0" to the 'text' property of your textfield - In other words you are NOT checking if it is EQUALS-TO "0".

You have to use the double-equals operator to return the desired outcome:

```
if(txtValue.text == "0") { ... }
```

This will then pass through your statement correctly.

Only some rare cases, you will wish to do an assignment (instead of 'checking' a condition) within the if-statement. This can often be found in file-reading or reference-checking statements like the following:

```
var someVar:Array;
if(someVar = methodThatCanReturnList()) { ... }
```

But this method is a bit frown upon. And for beginners it is much more recommended to master the "==" operator first.